# Excel VBA to extract Hyperlink from Hyperlink Formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, hyperlink

I am trying to write VBA code to validate links on spreadsheet. I have it working well until I encountered Hyperlinks created from formula. For example `=Hyperlink(A1,"Link1")` or `=Hyperlink(A1&A2,"Link2")`

The standard `Hyperlinks(1).Address` VBA does not register these as having link, and I cannot find any other solutions online.

Any ideas?

Comment: Unclear............do you want to convert the formula into an *Inserted Hyperlink*??

Comment: I want to check a hyperlink that was created from the Hyperlink function actually has a valid address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple approach that will handle **some** of your formulas.  Say **A1** contains the formula:

```
=HYPERLINK("http://www.google.com","search")
```

If we select it and run:

```
Sub HyperChecker()
    Dim s1 As String, s2 As String, arr

    s1 = ActiveCell.Formula
    s2 = Mid(s1, 12)
    arr = Split(s2, ",")
    MsgBox arr(0)
End Sub
```

we get:

[image]

The code discards the beginning and end of the formula and returns the URL.

The problem arises if the first argument of the function is an *expression* rather than a *string constant*.

You would then need to `EVALUATE()` that expression.

Comment: That is about as far as I got with my code. When links have been created from nested formula it becomes a lot more complex. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @aliw1  I have a couple of ideas on attacking complex hyperlinks.  If you want, I will update this Answer later today.

Answer (score 0):

For the more general case, you can simply use something like:

```
url_formula = Split(Mid(cell.formula, 12), ",")(0)
Debug.Print Evaluate(url_formula)
```

Where `Mid(cell.formula, 12)` gets rid of the `=HYPERLINK(` part of the formula, and `Split(..., ",")(0)` splits the rest of the formula at the comma part (the `(0)` selects the first part of the split - and is thus zero-based unlike most of the indexing in Excel).

Then, use the `Evaluate` function to evaluate the resulting expression. This should be fairly general, at least as general as the `Evaluate` function allows.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers don't handle variations in the formula very well.  For example, they fail if the formula contains both the LINK_LOCATION parameter and the FRIENDLY_NAME parameter.  Others also fail if the formula has extra spaces or line breaks in certain areas.

This answer isn't perfect but it works better than other answers I have found as of the date I am posting this.  I have identified cases where this code will work and where it will fail.

This VBA function is a bit long but it will extract the URL/address of a hyperlink either from a HYPERLINK() formula or a non-formula hyperlink imbedded in a cell.

It checks for a non-formula hyperlink first since that is the easiest and most reliably extracted hyperlink.  If one doesn't exist it checks for a hyperlink in a formula.

Extraction from a formula ONLY works if there is nothing outside the HYPERLINK() function except an equal sign.

### Acceptable HYPERLINK() Formulas

It **WILL** work on this formula:

```
=HYPERLINK("https://" & A1, "My Company Website")
```

It **WILL** work on this formula too (notice extra spaces and line breaks):

```
=    
HYPERLINK(     "https://" & A1, 
         "My Company Website" & B2)
```

It will **NOT** work on this formula:

```
=IF(  LEN(A1)=0, "", HYPERLINK("https://" & A1, "My Company Website")  )
```

### Function

```
Function HyperLinkText(ByVal Target As Excel.Range) As String
    
    ' If TARGET is multiple cells, only check the first cell.
    Dim firstCellInTarget As Excel.Range
    Set firstCellInTarget = Target.Cells.Item(1)
    
    
    Dim returnString As String
    
    
    ' First check if the cell contains a non-formula hyperlink.
    If Target.Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then
        ' Cell contains a non-formula hyperlink.
        returnString = Target.Hyperlinks.Item(1).Address    ' extract hyperlink text from the Hyperlinks property of the range
    
    Else
        ' Cell does -NOT- contain a non-formula hyperlink.
        '   Check for a formula hyperlink.
        Dim targetFormula As String
        targetFormula = firstCellInTarget.Formula
        
        
        
        Dim firstOpenParenthesisIndex As Long
        firstOpenParenthesisIndex = VBA.InStr(1, _
                                              targetFormula, _
                                              "(", _
                                              VbCompareMethod.vbBinaryCompare)
        
        Dim cleanFormulaHyperlinkPrefix As String
        cleanFormulaHyperlinkPrefix = Left$(targetFormula, firstOpenParenthesisIndex)
        cleanFormulaHyperlinkPrefix = Replace$(Replace$(Replace$(cleanFormulaHyperlinkPrefix, Space$(1), vbNullString), vbCr, vbNewLine), vbLf, vbNullString)
        
        Dim cleanFormulaPart2 As String
        cleanFormulaPart2 = Mid$(targetFormula, firstOpenParenthesisIndex + 1)
        
        Dim cleanFormulaCombined As String
        cleanFormulaCombined = cleanFormulaHyperlinkPrefix & cleanFormulaPart2
        
        
        ' Get all text inside the HYPERLINK() function.
        '   This is either a single LINK_LOCATION parameter or both the
        '   LINK_LOCATION and FRIENDLY_NAME parameters separated by a comma.
        '
        '   Ex. 1 Parameter:        "https://" & $A$1
        '   Ex. 2 Parameters:       "https://" & $A$1, "Click Here To Open the Company URL"
        '
        Const HYPERLINK_FORMULA_PREFIX As String = "=HYPERLINK("
                
        Dim tmpString As String
        tmpString = Mid$(cleanFormulaCombined, VBA.Len(HYPERLINK_FORMULA_PREFIX) + 1)
        
        Dim textInsideHyperlinkFunction As String
        textInsideHyperlinkFunction = Left$(tmpString, VBA.Len(tmpString) - 1)
        
        
        ' Get the first parameter (LINK_LOCATION) from the text inside the HYPERLINK()
        '   function by using =EVALUATE().  If text inside the HYPERLINK() function
        '   contains two parameters, they will be separated by a comma and EVALUATE()
        '   will return an error.  Start with the entire text inside the HYPERLINK()
        '   function.  If EVALUATE() returns an error, remove one character from the end
        '   of the string being evaluated and try again.  Eventually only one parameter
        '   will be evaluated and EVALUATE() will return a text string.
        '
        '   For example, if the string to be evaluated is:
        '
        '       "https://" & $A$1, "Click Here To Open the Company URL"
        '
        '   and cell A1 contains:
        '
        '       mycompany.com
        '
        '   EVALUATE will return:
        '
        '       https://mycompany.com
        '
        Dim hyperlinkLinkLocation As String
        Dim i As Long
        For i = VBA.Len(textInsideHyperlinkFunction) To 1 Step -1   ' with each failure, shrink length of string-to-evaluate by one

            If Not VBA.IsError(Excel.Application.Evaluate("=" & Left$(textInsideHyperlinkFunction, i))) Then
                hyperlinkLinkLocation = Excel.Application.Evaluate("=" & Left$(textInsideHyperlinkFunction, i))
                Exit For        ' ****
            End If

        Next i
        
        returnString = hyperlinkLinkLocation

    End If
    
    
    ' Return the hyperlink string.
    HyperLinkText = returnString
End Function
```

### How to Use the Function

```
Sub Test()
    ' Display hyperlink of the first cell
    '    in the currently selected range.
    Msgbox HyperLinkText(Selection) ' displays the hyperlink of the first cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.